# Trying to find the name of the manga with an AI robot girl and a boy that got isekaied

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm looking for the name of a manga where there's an AI robot girl with blonde hair, and a teenage boy who got isekaied (I think), and trying to build some kingdom or something.

I haven't read the manga, and I didn't bookmark it and it's been long so there's no history about it in my browser. Now I want to read it, but I forgot the title.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://myanimelist.net/anime/5781/Isekai_no_Seikishi_Monogatari?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a perfect match but I haven't found any other isekai or kingdom building stories tagged with "robot/s" or "artificial intelligence".

This may be *[Mynoghra the Apocalypse: World Conquest by Civilization of Ruin](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/isekai-mokushiroku-mynoghra-hametsu-no-bunmei-de-hajimeru-sekai-seifuku)*, aka *Isekai Mokushiroku Mynoghra: Hametsu no Bunmei de Hajimeru Sekai Seifuku*

> I **reincarnated** as an evil god. Ira Takuto succumbed to illness at a **young age** and ended up reincarnating in a world that resembled the strategy simulation game, "Eternal Nations", of which he loved playing when alive. What appeared in front of him was Atou, a girl belonging to the evil civilization that he used to play as, "Mynoghra". **The two of them decided to create a new country in this world once again**.

The main character dies and is reborn within a game he used to play, alongside his attendant Atou. Atou has silver/blueish hair, not blonde, but in a black&white manga they both appear light. Atou is a character from the game and is aware of the world being that of a game. She is not a robot, and in universe she appears to be the same as any other humanoid, but I believe "self-aware character from a game" is reasonably close to her being considered an AI.